# Using libspotify for a web-based application

Tags: spotify

I simply am wondering if the only way to have any sort of spotify application be web-based, as opposed to app-based, would be to have it as a Spotify app within the Spotify application or if it's possible to have it standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting confused between our APIs.

- Spotify Apps is a platform inside our Spotify client. You write them using HTML5/JavaScript. They're run locally, but you can have it talk to a backend service if you wish.
- Spotify's Web API provides HTTP REST services for search and metadata lookup.
- libSpotify is for standalone native applications. You *can* have that application host a web service — there are Ruby bindings, for instance — but there are a few Terms of Service you need to be aware of concerning logging in as a user from your own service. You can find the ToS on http://developer.spotify.com.

Comment: Do you know of any PHP bindings for libSpotify?

Comment: Googling "PHP libspotify" gives a ton of results.

Comment: In the Terms of Use for libSpotify, it says "You may not: ... attempt to embed or integrate the API into any website or otherwise allow access to the Service via the web rather than via the Application."  Do the terms mean direct access, then, given what you're saying?  For example, we can use Libspotify server-side, but we can't just expose its features verbatim?