# Using Spotify APIs for a web application

Tags: api, spotify, libspotify

I am a little confused with libspotify
I want to include Spotify in my web application. I plan to use the java wrapper for this (https://github.com/nvdweem/libjahspotify).

I want to know if it is ok to do it this way and that it is not only to be used to build native apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it is not ok.

> you may not:
>   8. attempt to embed or integrate the API into any website or otherwise allow access to the Service via the web rather than via the
>   Application.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/terms-of-use-non-us/

Comment: I'm curious about this as well, because someone who at least sounds like they're working through spotify seemed to imply that it was okay in some manner... but I'm not sure whether I'm misunderstanding him:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191001/using-libspotify-for-a-web-based-application

I'll be interested to see what he says, as there'd be a lot of potentially useful things a person could do if they were allowed to use the Spotify API server-side.